# Autocomplete for combobox items with trim text vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Please help me
i need autocomplete combobox item with type trim text , my items example:

```
mralexdaiv
drjohnoon
sralexii
vmjohner
eaalexmn
```

if i type "john" then give me autocomplete items mralexdaiv , sralexii , eaalexmn

example2 : my item in combobox "redblueblack" i need find item with type "blue"

im give that and the value its ok

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ComboBox2.Items.Count - 1
    Dim value As String = ComboBox2.GetItemText(ComboBox2.Items(i))

    If value.Contains(ComboBox2.Text) Then

    Else



    End If
Next
```

Comment: The `ComboBox` control has auto-complete functionality built in but it won't do that. It will only match the start of an item. What you could do is, as the user types text into the control, filter the drop-down item list and match that text anywhere. The user could then select a matching item from the drop-down list and you could clear the filter. If that sounds OK, let me know and I'll try to provide an answer that demonstrates that.

Comment: I don't really understand your first example. You seem to be saying that you want to choose from items that don't match the value you type, but then the second example implies you want items that do match. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Sure my combobox items is 
Albasragov
Thisbaghdadcom
Redblueblack

I need if write in combo box
“basra” then give me “Albasragov”
“baghda” then give me “Thisbaghdadcom”
“blue” then give me “Redblueblack”

Comment: A lot of people seem not to understand the difference between an explanation and an example. You need to actually detail the rules you're trying to implement, not just what the results should be in one or two specific cases. Also, I asked you to edit your question to clarify the problem. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: Also, I specific asked whether my initial suggestion seems like an acceptable solution and you seem to have just ignored that. I'm not going to write an answer that may not be of any use so if you want that answer you're going to have to provide the confirmation I asked for.

Comment: sorry i want items that match with my ComboBox2_TextChanged

Comment: @يوسفالبياتي What is the connection between "john" and "mralexdaiv", "sralexii", and "eaalexmn" in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

Done..

```
    Private Sub ComboBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.TextChanged

        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\Governorates\mytext.txt"))

        ComboBox3.Items.Clear()
        listNew2.Clear()

        For Each item In ListBox1.Items

            If item.ToLower().Contains(ComboBox3.Text) Then
                listNew2.Add(item)
            End If
        Next

        ComboBox3.Items.AddRange(listNew2.ToArray())
        ComboBox3.SelectionStart = ComboBox3.Text.Length
        Cursor = Cursors.[Default]
        If ComboBox3.Text = "" Then

        Else
            ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True

        End If

    End Sub
```